# Как сделать четкую рамку при наведении (SVG)?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Изучаю `SVG` графику. Пытаюсь сделать логотип, хочу что бы при наведении заливка менялась у самого блока и у буквы, это сделать получилось. Так же хотелось, чтобы появлялась обводка у блока, но если делать это средствами `SVG`, то она получается совершенно не четкая:

```html
<svg height='50' width='50' vievBox='0 0 50 50'>
  <style>
    .polylogobox {
      fill: #ef402a;
      transition: .2s;
    }
    .polylogobox:hover {
      fill: #fff;
  stroke: #ef402a;
  stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    .polylogobox:hover + text {
      fill: #ef402a;
    }
    text {
      font-size: 30px;
      fill: #fff;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      transition: .2s;
    }
  </style>
  <polygon class='polylogobox' points='0,0 24,0 28,5 50,5, 50,50 0,50 '/>
  <text x='14' y='38'>E</text>
</svg>
```

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В первый ответ добавил красную рамку `style="border:1px solid red;"`чтобы видно было реальные границы `svg`.
 Именно столько места `150x150px` будет занимать иконка при верстке `Html` странички, образуя тем самым большие отступы от остальных элементов странички. 
Нужно расширить `viewBox` но всего на `6px`, чтобы сделать отступы минимальными - `3px`

И так:  `viewBox="-3 -3 56 56"`

Ниже полный код. Красную рамку оставил для наглядности:

```html
<svg height="56" width="56" viewBox="-3 -3 56 56" style="border:1px solid red;" >
  <style>
    .polylogobox {
      fill:#ef402a;
      transition: .2s;
    }
    .polylogobox:hover {
      fill: #fff;
  stroke: #ef402a;
  stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    .polylogobox:hover + text {
      fill: #ef402a;
    }
    text {
      font-size: 30px;
      fill: #fff;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      transition: .2s;
    }
  </style>
  <polygon class='polylogobox' points='0,0 24,0 28,5 50,5, 50,50 0,50 '/>
  <text x='14' y='38' pointer-events="none">E</text>
</svg>
```

### UPDATE

*По замечаниям в комментариях*
Текст находится на слой выше полигона `<polygon>` поэтому экранирует  `:hover` на букве.
Для устранения экранирования применим к тексту стиль  `pointer-events="none"`, который сделает текст прозрачным для событий мышки.

`<text x='14' y='38' pointer-events="none">E</text>`

Comment: Сама суть ясна, я увеличил `viewBox` & размеры(значения) для наглядного примера:)

Comment: @St1myL но пользователь скопирует 1:1 И долго будет ломать голову, почему у него такие огромные отступы

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, а как лучше всего вставлять такой логотип? Сохранять файлом, и как обычную картинку? Или лучше куском кода прямо вставлять в верстку?

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi Надежнее всего скопировать 1:1 в любое место `HTML` Такой способ называется инлайн добавление svg

Comment: Т.е. обернуть в div и вставить на страницу?

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi да,   обернуть в div и с его помощью можно дополнительно позиционировать

Comment: но тут получается, что если навести курсор на красное поле, то hover отработает и цвет изменится, но если перевести курсор на букву, то опять фон станет красным, а курсор больше не будет указателем. я, конечно, не знаю, что точно нужно топикстартеру, но по-моему это не совсем правильное поведение.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, в моём примере он был изначально:)))

Answer (score 5):

В вашем примере `stroke` везде одинаковой толщины, нужно лишь изменить поле видимости, то есть `viewBox` и размеры самого `SVG`, вот исправленный пример:

```css
.polylogobox {
  fill: #ef402a;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.polylogobox:hover {
  fill: #fff;
}

.polylogobox:hover+text {
  fill: #ef402a;
}

text {
  font-size: 30px;
  fill: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  transition: 0.2s;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<svg height='150' width='150' viewBox="-10 -10 150 150" style="Border:1px solid red;">
  <polygon class='polylogobox' points='0,0 24,0 28,5 50,5, 50,50 0,50' stroke-width="4" stroke="#ef402a"/>
  <text x='14' y='38'>E</text> 
</svg>
```